# thinking sphinx partially rebuilding index?

Tags: indexing, thinking-sphinx

After running a script to populate my database i ran a `rake ts:rebuild` but sphinx is partially rebuilding the indexes.

```
Stopped searchd daemon (pid: 23309).
Generating configuration to /home/guest_dp/config/development.sphinx.conf
Sphinx 2.1.4-id64-release (rel21-r4421)
Copyright (c) 2001-2013, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2013, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
using config file '/home/guest_dp/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'episode_core'...
collected 4469 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 4469 docs, 8938 bytes
total 0.071 sec, 124488 bytes/sec, 62244.07 docs/sec
indexing index 'episode_delta'...
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.013 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
indexing index 'organization_core'...
.
. 
.
skipping non-plain index 'episode'...
skipping non-plain index 'organization'...
skipping non-plain index 'person'...
skipping non-plain index 'position'...
skipping non-plain index 'profession'...
skipping non-plain index 'segment'...
skipping non-plain index 'tv_show'...
total 12816 reads, 0.005 sec, 0.2 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 116 writes, 0.020 sec, 52.3 kb/call avg, 0.1 msec/call avg
Started searchd successfully (pid: 23571).
```

What does it mean `skipping non-plain index` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of those are distributed indices, which contain the `_core` and `_delta` plain indices (e.g. `episode` contains both `episode_core` and `episode_delta`). There's nothing to do to index them directly, because distributed indices don't contain data, they just point to other indices.

In other words: what you're seeing is completely normal. All of your indices are being processed appropriately.

Sphinx used to have a slightly different message: `Distributed index 'episode' can not be directly indexed; skipping` - [same deal](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/thinking-sphinx/xO9rDJw1d5w/GJ6FdnBHJksJ).